# Build your own puzzle!

Tags: logical-deduction, word, grid-deduction, sudoku, crosswords

This grid contains 3 puzzles all in one;  [0h n0](https://0hn0.com/), a Crossword and a Wordoku (Sudoku with letters)...

...but first you'll need to build it.

---

[image]

---

#### 0h n0

1. Cells can 'see' other blue cells in the same row and column
2. A cell filled in red blocks their view
3. The number shows how many blue cells the clued cells can 'see'

#### Crossword

IMPORTANT: **The grid is conventionally numbered and connected** - however only a randomly ordered list of clues is given:

First half of a south asian country
Term for US Soldier
Equal
Tanker company's ticker symbol
Famous australian singer and songwriter
Area for creation of salt
Impure compound in portland cement
The act of removing
One of human babies primitive reflexes
Shortened version of name meaning 'gave'
Rocket that uses nuclear fission
Get up
Irish for a classical element

#### Wordoku

Regular sudoku rules, except there are 9 unique letters instead of numbers 1-9

---

### Use the given information to solve the 3 puzzles to find the final word!

Tip: You'll have to use multiple puzzles at the same time to solve this, it can't be solved one at a time!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I solved the three puzzles! The final word is:

> **TRIANGLES**

---

I'm new to this site, so I apologize in advance if my answer is too concise (or too detailed), please let me know in the comments if that's the case. Below is my solution of each individual puzzle.

> First I solved the 0h n0 puzzle, taking into account the restrictions that the final blue grid must form a conventionally numbered and connected crossword.

> [image: Solution to the first puzzle]

> Here is the solution to the crossword:
>
>  [image: Solution to the second puzzle]
>
> Across:
>
> 1. Term for US Soldier: **[GI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I.#:%7E:text=G.I.%20are%20initials%20used%20to,general%20items%20of%20their%20equipment.)**
> 4. Tanker company's ticker symbol: **[STNG](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/stng) (Scorpio Tankers Inc.)**
> 6. Irish for a classical element: **AER** (the classical element "air" in Irish)
> 7. One of human babies primitive reflexes: **[ATNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetrical_tonic_neck_reflex)** (Asymmetrical Tonic Neck Reflex)
> 8. Area for creation of salt: **[SALTERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saltern)**
> 10. The act of removing:  **ERASING**
>
> Down:
>
> 2. Equal: **IS**
> 3. First half of a south asian country: **SRIL** (from Sri Lanka)
> 5. Rocket that uses nuclear fission: **[NTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket)** (Nuclear Thermal Rocket)
> 6. Impure compound in portland cement: **[ALITE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alite)**
> 7. Get up: **ARISE**
> 8. Famous australian singer and songwriter: **SIA**
> 9. Shortened version of name meaning 'gave': **NATE** (short for [Nathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_(given_name)))
>
>  I was unable to guess one of the clues at first (Equal -> IS), but luckily that clue wasn't really needed to solve it.

> Finally, here is the solution to the wordoku. The highlighted diagonal contains the final word TRIANGLES (unless I'm missing something).

> [image: Solution to the third puzzle]

Comment: Correct!! Great job, and very nice answer, almost perfect - only thing really missing I'd say is perhaps a list of the crossword answers, but I can add that if you need, might be quicker as I have all the questions and links already next to each other :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh, sorry, I had a list but I forgot to add it! I just edited the answer.

Comment: Cleaned it up a little, but great answer! Glad you realised the crossword restrictions for the 0h n0 at the start :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks for the edit, and for a wonderful puzzle! :) Yeah, I saw the restriction highlighted in bold and realised that the only point where that information would matter is when solving the 0h n0 puzzle.